# Pipenv virtual environment pulling me into different directories

Tags: python, django, github, heroku, pipenv

I have installed `pipenv` on my machine to run virtual environments. My problem is that when i run `pipenv`, it keeps pulling me back to a different folder. For example, I build a project in my `pycharmprojects` folder. I navigate to that project from my terminal. `cd pycharmprojects` then `cd myproject`. Then when I run a virtual enrolment in that folder `pipenv shell`, I get pulled back to `/Users/myname/PycharmProjects`.

This is where my `pipfile`, `piffle.lock` and `Procfile` seem to live as well. I am getting a error when trying to deploy to heroku and I am wondering if it is something to do with this issue  based on my virtual environment. The error im getting with deploying to heroku is:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-heroku-app-123.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not because of `virutalenv` or `pipenv`, what this means is that the commit you are deploying has changed the git history-- either through squashing, rebasing, or amending the commit message etc.

You could check the logs, verify the commits and then force-push to master, assuming origin is the remote and master is the branch.

```sh
$ git log 
$ git push origin master -f
`
```